# What exactly does this "play a country song backwards" joke mean?

Tags: meaning, jokes

So I come across this joke,which rather confuses me.

> — What do you get when you play a country song backwards?
>   — You get your house back, your wife back, your dog back, your truck back...

I just wonder what the relationship is between *a country song* and all the others. Can someone show me any background knowledge about this joke?

Comment: Country songs are notorious for recounting bad luck.  In the songs people invariably lose the things they hold dear- their wife, their dog, their truck.

Comment: Funny joke, but "Jokes that do not rely on the English language" are off topic http://english.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Urbycoz: Good point, but, in this case, one could argue that _country music_ has enough of a subculture (to include language), that the question is on-topic. [This book review](http://www.countrystandardtime.com/d/bookreview.asp?xid=6) alludes to that possibility.

Comment: The answer to the first line quoted lies in the second. An explanation of it is properly in the domain of ethno-music studies, not English language. Must try appropriate site. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: The trouble is, the question is off topic if you know the answer but until then it may well be considered on topic.

Comment: @neil True, but that does not make the question less off topic. The joke does not rely on the English language except in the banal sense that it is written in English. The OP seems to be asking for help to understand a joke (explicitly off topic) and to understand the cultural reference "a country song" (too basic for the site). OP please google `[ country music themes ]` for lots of information about the meaning of a country song.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: I don't think [that query](http://www.google.com/search?q=country+music+themes) completely answers the question; there are many possible sources of confusion here. Sure, there are the recurring themes of country music, but what does it mean to "play a song backwards?" For younger members of the Millennial Generation - who may not have a CD collection, owing to all their music being stored in .mp3 files - that part of the joke may also be confusing.

Comment: @J.R. Paraphrasing, the question is "what exactly does this joke mean" and more specifically "how does 'a country song' function within the joke". I see no indication the OP is confused or wondering about what it means to play a song backwards. And if I'm wrong then the question needs to be improved.

Comment: Actually, this question is on topic. It goes right to usage and language skills with the word "backward." Here, "backward" is used in a figurative, not a literal, sense. If I were to say I was so sad I could cry my eyes out, that is figuratively speaking, as of course I cannot literally cry my eyes out of my head. Here, "backward" refers to the imagery of the sequence of events in the song occurring in reverse, not the words so much themselves. So if the scene visualized by the song creates someone coming out of a door, backward they are walking backward back behind the door. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] It would not be "free" becomes "eerf."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the 1960's, some music groups recorded tracks on songs that sounded like gibberish, but, if the record was played backward (remember, these were vinyl records, so you could place the record on your turntable, and the needle on the record, and turn the record with your fingertip), the gibberish would become ungarbled, and a clear message could be heard.  (This is called [backmasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backmasking).)  Perhaps the most [famous](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=beatles%20paul%20is%20dead%20backwards&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) of these messages was one that said "Paul is dead" on the Beatles' song *Number 9*.  (This example is so popular, you can still buy a [T-shirt](https://www.google.com/search?q=paul+is+dead+t-shirt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=paul+is+dead+t-shirt&hl=en&safe=off&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=NYxiUb36E8uE2QWh-oDQBQ&ved=0CDoQsxg&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.b2I&fp=46a465224cfb8e9c&biw=1176&bih=876).)

Country music is known for lyrics where songwriters lament about things that are lost (lost loves who have walked away, lost fortunes that have been squandered away, etc.). David Allan Coe even made fun of this, in a way, at the end of his song *You Never Even Called Me by My Name*:

> (*spoken*) Well a friend of mine named Steve Goodman wrote that song
> And he told me it was the perfect country and western song
> I wrote him back a letter and I told him it was not the perfect country and western song
> Because he hadn't said anything at all about momma or trains or trucks or prison or gettin' drunk

> (*still spoken*) Well he sat down and wrote another verse to this song
> And he sent it to me and after reading it I realized that my friend
> had written the perfect country and western song
> And I felt obliged to include it on this album
> The last verse goes like this here

> (*sung*) Well I was drunk the day my mom got out of prison
> And I went to pick her up in the rain
> But before I could get to the station in the pick-up truck
> She got runned over by a damned old train

So, put those two things together – backmasking, and recurring themes in country music – and you should be able to understand the joke.

Comment: What is 'backmasking'?

Comment: @Mitch: It's when something is "recorded backwards" on the studio mixer board, and dubbed into the recording that way. (My sentence structure got a little long; sorry if you or anyone else thought that _backmasking_ referred to playing it back with your finger on a turntable.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had never heard the word before, and context didn't disambiguate from all the things mentioned. 'masking' made me think of something else.

Comment: The problem with this explanation is that the back-masked content was typically completely different than the forward-played content. Perhaps this is just a weakness in the joke, but IMHO the joke is talking about replaying the *events* of the song backwards, not the sounds themselves.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I suppose we'll all take the joke differently, but, to me, the joke is more funny, given the dotted history of big-name artists embedding hidden messages in backmasked snippets – why else would you play the song backwards? The Beatles, Pink Floyd, Ozzy Osbourne, Frank Zappa and Prince all tinkered with it, according to [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backmasked_messages). Even "Weird Al" got into the act, backmasking a parody of a backmask: _Satan eats Cheese Whiz_. Yas ot evah I lla staht.

Comment: It seems to me that the joke depends upon the reader being familiar with backmasking. The explanation is a good one.

Comment: It's overstating it to imply that "Paul is dead" was on purpose. The supposedly "clear" messages when songs are played backwards are really not that clear in many cases. Having said that, there are cases of (alleged) back-masking that are not gibberish when played forwards, and a perfectly clear English phrase sounds like another phrase when played backwards, e.g., "Another One Bites The Dust" sounds like "It's fun to smoke marijuana" (but not clearly, I remember when I first heard it demonstrated back in the 80s I thought that I might not have understood what it said if not told in advance).

Comment: [continued] But yes, I've always understood the backwards country song joke to be in the context of back-masking.

Answer (score 12):

In country songs the subject is often woeful, at least stereotypically it is. Typically the songs lyrics revolve around losing things such as your house, your wife (or husband), your dog, your vehicle (typically a truck). If you were to play it backwards, as if time itself is rolling backwards, you stop losing all those things and gain them instead.

Answer (score 2):

Country music tends to be rather melancholy, and a stereotypical song might be "I lost my truck, I lost my dog, I lost my wife, I lost my home."

Reversing its meaning gives you it all back again.

The joke is that you cannot reverse the meaning by playing the song backwards.

Comment: Reversing does? Playing the song backward would change words to their antonyms?!

Comment: Yes, of course. Have you not tried it?! :-) Alternatively, we could just reverse the meaning.

Comment: If it does, that's not the joke here. I'm afraid you're missing the whole point.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yeah, that's the joke actually. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many country songs especially older ones talk about things that are lost - wife, family, freedom, truck, better times, etc. Playing the song backwards gets you everything back because you un-lose them by playing it backwards. You get everything back. Un-lose. It's funny to me. I don't think there's any intention to speak to backward masking with that joke. That was a rock music thing not a country thing.

Also the relationship between country music specifically is that those themes of loss are typical of country music while not so much for rock music or other popular music forms.